# LED light in the gap between tile and ceiling

Tags: lighting, tile, led, tiling

My house has wood planks on the ceiling, which over the years became unleveled, so it's impossible to install large format tile without a gap between the ceiling and the tile edge. That's the best I managed to do above the vanity:

[image]

On the bathtub side, it's unleveled even more. I'm thinking to use it as an advantage and put a watertight LED light strip behind the tile so it would look close to [this](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/324540716888802251/).

I prepared the wiring and a small deepening covered with schluter membrane at the top so the strip could sit there and even be replaced in the future (won't be easy though):

[image]

The side section would look like this:
[image]

Does this sound reasonable or am I missing some obvious issues?

Is it ok to have 1/8-1/4 in. gap between tile and ceiling? Surprisingly it does not look bad to me, but I'm curious what people think

Comment: You're asking for opinions, so this might get closed. One thing I can tell you for sure: plan so that this can be replaced. LED strips fail at an annoyingly high rate, and it's tough to tell which ones are the bad ones.

Comment: You've created a gutter that's going to fill with water from condensation.

Comment: @brhans that's the most useful comment here. that makes a lot of thanks, thank you

Comment: @Tetsujin I am unencumbered by my surroundings.

Answer (score 3):

Aesthetically, your suggestion seems to not only trap LEDs into the wall, but also light up an uneven edge, drawing everyone's attention to it.

Alternatively, find some LED strip you can stick on top of the tiles, filling the gap to best fit & overlapping tile where it's tightest.
That way your light feature will mask the variation, rather than highlight it.

[image]

<sup>Scuse the fine art ;)</sup>

If you find some that is encapsulated inside aluminium/translucent plastic, then if a strip fails, you only need to replace the 'element' inside, not the whole structure.

e.g…

[image]

<sup>Only one I have to hand. This one isn't waterproof & also has a magnetic back strip. It's designed to slap easily onto shelving in retail stores. Easy in, easy out..</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would just fill that gap with white putty/paintable caulk/spackling compound. Without the shadow line, nobody will notice the transition.

And frankly, even if you leave it this way, odds are nobody will notice but you... people don't pay much attention to ceilings.

Besides, you've already got those big horizontal and vertical shadow lines in the middle of the wall so this looks like a design decision rather than an error.

One other suggestion: Install some kind of trim that covers the top edge of the tile. You can make that tight to both ceiling and wall,big it's either flexible or in short enough pieces, and it will hide the hint that the tiles may not be perfectly tight against the ceiling.

(Nothing in an older house is ever perfectly plumb or square...)